# Make comparator more reusable

Tags: java, comparator

I created a comparator and used enum to order things.. Its working, but i want to reuse this Comparator so I can use different types of Enum like TruckOrderEnum, PlaneOrderEnum.

```
public class BrandComparator implements Comparator<Brand> {
        public int compare(Brand o1, Brand o2) {

            String s1= Optional.ofNullable(CarOrderEnum.getById(m1.getId()))
                    .map(CarOrderEnum::getOrder).orElse(m1.getDescription());

            String s2= Optional.ofNullable(CarOrderEnum.getById(m2.getId()))
                    .map(CarOrderEnum::getOrder).orElse(m2.getDescription());

            return s1.compareTo(s2);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use one comparator for two case if there is no relation with them. For example if TruckOrderEnum's order is null we use PlaneOrderEnum's value.

Comment: instead of creating new BrandComparator  (BrandTruckComparator) just to use TruckOrderEnum.. i hope there is an efficient way

Comment: How your programm will be identify on what Enum it need to compare?